# How to get my contract balance in my smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract

I have copy the `account` struct from the smart contract `eosio.token` into my own contract and typedef multi_index like this:
`//@abi table accounts i64 
struct account 
{
    asset balance; 
    uint64_t primary_key() const { return balance.symbol.name(); } 
};`

`typedef eosio::multi_index<N(accounts), account> accounts;`

And I define a `accounts` type variable named `accountstable` which code is `N(eosio.token)` and scope is `_self`. Code is here:

`accounts accountstable(N(eosio.token), _self); 
const auto &ac = accountstable.get(CORE_SYMBOL); 
return ac.balance;`

But this doesn't work for me and get the error message means can not find the key. Something wrong?

Comment: So you're trying to determine the balance of an account inside the contract itself? You're not querying the balance of a user externally?

Comment: Yes! I want to get the balance of my contract account inside the contract!

Comment: Can you throw up the whole project/contract on a GitHub repo? I'll take a look.

Comment: I am not sure, but this might help: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/638

Comment: If you're using eosio.cdt >= 1.3.0, I answered a very similar question here: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/3958/2944.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

`symbol_type symbol(S(4,SYS));
const auto& ac = accountstable.get(symbol.name());`

You cannot `.get(CORE_SYMBOL)` for some reason. I dunno. This had me stumped for hours.