# How to send an action from one contract to another?

Tags: smart-contract, action

From contract A, I want to send an action to contract B.
How to do that?

There is `SEND_INLINE_ACTION` but that seems to need a pointer to the contract (usually `*this`), correct?

**Solution**

Using `action.send` as suggested by Leo works when having set `eosio.code` permission to the contract's account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use `N(yourcontract)` instead of `*this`. If it does not work you can also try this:

```
    action(permission_level{ from, N(active) },
           N(eosio.token), N(transfer),
           std::make_tuple(from, self, price, std::string(""))
    ).send();
```

Instead of `N(eosio.token)` and `N(transfer)` you would use the external contract that you want.

The external contract should allow transactions coming from your contract.

Comment: `N(yourcontract)` does not work.

Comment: `action(..).send()` only works if the permission is set to `eosio.code`, i.e. it was manually set.

Comment: What do you mean by `contract should allow transactions coming from your contract`? How to allow or disallow a user?

Comment: it requires you to give eosio.code permission only if you try a `eosio.token::transfer` like above or any other contract/action that you try to use this method?

Comment: It was required for me for a normal action "changepet"

Answer (score 0):

Here we can see an [**example from Monstereos**](https://github.com/leordev/monstereos/blob/master/contracts/pet/lib/pet.battle.cpp) sending an inline action for the battlecreate function:

```
void pet::battlecreate(name host, battle_mode mode, checksum256 secret) {
  require_auth(host);

  _tb_battle tb_battles(_self, _self);
  auto itr_battle = tb_battles.find(host);

  eosio_assert(itr_battle == tb_battles.end(), "you already host a battle!");
  eosio_assert(mode == V1 || mode == V2 || mode == V3, "invalid battle mode");

  // check and increase busy arenas counter
  auto pc = _get_pet_config();
  pc.battle_busy_arenas++;
  eosio_assert(pc.battle_busy_arenas <= pc.battle_max_arenas, "all arenas are busy");

  tb_battles.emplace(_self, [&](auto& r) {
    r.host = host;
    r.mode = mode;
  });
  _update_pet_config(pc);

  SEND_INLINE_ACTION( *this, battlejoin, {host,N(active)}, {host, host, secret} );
}
```

---

### SEND_INLINE_ACTION | [**Docs**](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/reference#send_inline_action)

Parameters

```
CONTRACT - The account this action is intended for
NAME - The name of the action
... - The member of the action specified as ("action_member1_name", action_member1_value)("action_member2_name", action_member2_value)
```

So:

`*this` is the dereferenced pointer of value contract

`battlejoin` being the name of the action

battlejoin calls for: `name host, name player, checksum256 secret`

So we give it `host` with an `active` permission level for verification, `host` for host, `host` for player, and `checksum256` for match's secret ID.

Comment: Can you explain how to get a different contract than `*this`?

Comment: the first parameter is called CONTRACT but the description states it's an account.  a contract is a class, not an account.  so does it mean the account owning the contract that this action is intended to call?  the documentation is confusing to me